# Watch another elements classes with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use the Bootstrap javascript components to create toggleable panels. For each panel the class `in` is set, if it is currently opened. I'd like to show a *Font Awesome* icon depending on the current panel state.

`fa fa-angle-up` when it's open, and `fa fa-angle-down` when it's closed.

However I have difficulties achieving it, as I can't figure out a proper AngularJS way to do it. My current approach is using the jQuery `hasClass()` method to check for the class and apply the correct Font Awesome class for the arrow.

As jQuery doesn't support Two-Way-Databinding this obviously has some issues. What I've figured is, that the method is called once and the proper class is set to the arrow, but when I open/close the panel the `ng-class` doesn't get re-evaluated to switch it.

What would be the correct "Angular-way" achieving this?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headlineEdit">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target='#collapseEdit' href="#collapseEdit" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEdit">
                <div class="leftside">Edit</div>
                <div class="rightside arrow-show"><span class="fa" ng-class="$('#collapseEdit').hasClass('in') ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down'"></span></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <!-- The "in" class determines whether the panel is opened or closed -->
    <div id="collapseEdit" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headlineEdit">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Placeholder text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Angular way is to encapsulate your bootstrap component in a directive and in there you can use jqlite, or plain javascript to change the classes based on whatever events you want.

Comment: @JoaoLeal Will this provide automatic re-evaluation of the class once the dependent `in` class changes, or would I need to bind an event or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with a directive:

```
app.directive('test',function(){
  return{
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {

      angular.element(el[0].querySelector('.rightside > .fa')).addClass('fa-angle-up');

      el.on('hide.bs.collapse', function(ev){
        angular.element(el[0].querySelector('.rightside > .fa'))
          .removeClass('fa-angle-up')
          .addClass('fa-angle-down');
      });

      el.on('show.bs.collapse', function(ev){
        angular.element(el[0].querySelector('.rightside > .fa'))
          .removeClass('fa-angle-down')
          .addClass('fa-angle-up'); 
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And just remove the `ng-class` attribute from your html.

Here's a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xo8Oqc68ZrWTIHa5ajDI?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

The Angular way is to store panel state in controller's scope and make view dependent on it. Something like this:

View:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="PanelCtrl">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" ng-click="toggle()" aria-expanded="isExpanded">
                <div class="leftside">Edit</div>
                <div class="rightside arrow-show"><span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-angle-up': !isExpanded, 'fa-angle-down': isExpanded}"></span></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <!-- The "in" class determines whether the panel is opened or closed -->
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{'in': isExpanded}" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Placeholder text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('PanelCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isExpanded = false;
    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.isExpanded = !$scope.isExpanded;
    };
}]);
```

As you're styling with Bootstrap, it might be easier for you to use [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). You can take a look at [their panel implementation](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js).

Comment: This works, but overrides the whole Bootstrap behavior. I've looked at Angular UI's panel implementation for the hide/show-animation, but it seems like I needed to implement a lot of code for the animation which is already in bootstrap.js